# Get Attribute Value PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom

this is source code which i am getting from remote source

```
<div class=hello>
<a class="abc" href="http://www.example.com" a1="Page1" a2="Wel-Come" data-image="example.com/1.jpeg">
<div>You are here</div>
.
.
.
<a class="abc" href="http://www.example.com" a1="Page2" a2="Aboutus" data-image="example.com/2.jpeg">
</div>
```

i am using php DOM Parser for parsing html i need this Output

```
Page1
http://www.example.com
<img src="example.com/1.jpeg">

Page2
http://www.example.com
<img src="example.com/2.jpeg">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       echo $element->a1;
       echo $element->image;
       echo "<img src='" . $element->image . "'/>";
}
```

Should work?

If direct access to ->a1 and ->image does not work, attempt:

```
$element->getAttribute('a1')
$element->getAttribute('image')
```

**EDIT:** This is the lib you are referring to, correct? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: *edited* image as data-image does it make any changes ? and is there any way to access content of <a.../> inside this specific <div class=hello> b'coz i have many images and href apart from this code